# Uploading local to server using php and ftp access

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to upload my local file to server with the following code copied from stackoverflow. I couldnt map the files right and looking for assistance.

I got two test cases with $localfile.

1. mapping with relative path using c:, it throws filename prohibited.
2. mapping with server path. it says connected and written successfully. But in server the file size is 0KB only.

The code:

```
//$local_file = 'C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\alaks\filestoanotherserver\sample.csv';
//Warning: ftp_put(): Prohibited file name: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\alaks\filestoanotherserver\sample.csv in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\alaks\filestoanotherserver\test.php on line 28
// The filename that i got the php code is test.ph
$local_file = 'sample.csv';    
//Connected!Successfully written to sample.csv - but not written. 
//The file size is showing 0KB.
$server_file = 'http://iseedtechnologies.in/sample.csv';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect("iseedtechnologies.in");

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, '****', '****');
echo is_array(ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".")) ? 'Connected!' : 'not Connected! :(';
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

**Working code**   (Removed the http:// and it worked)

```
$local_file = 'sample.csv';    

$server_file = 'sample.csv';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect("iseedtechnologies.in");

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, '****', '****');
echo is_array(ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".")) ? 'Connected!' : 'not Connected! :(';
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: The destination file path needs to be a filesystem path not an url.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I have updated the code too.